# Обновление маршрутов в Quagga без перезапуска?

Tags: сеть, роутер, маршрутизация

Сейчас маршруты пишутся скриптом в bgpd.conf и перезапускается quagga. Проблема в том, что рвётся bgp сессия с другими роутерами.

(Исходники тут: https://github.com/mironoff111/RKN_Tor_Gateway_BGP)

Вопрос: как это делать иначе?

Comment: Пусть скрипт коннектится телнетом к квагге (у нее вроде есть порт управления) и передает ей изменения командами

Comment: @Mike А где можно почитать про телнет? Какие команды кушает квага?

Comment: Вот этого я не знаю :) У меня знакомый с ней работает. На сколько я знаю там команды как у cisco. Собственно google на `quagga telnet` выдал http://muff.kiev.ua/content/quagga-prevrashchenie-servera-v-polnofunktsionalnyi-marshrutizator